# Regular expression negative lookbehind to ignore commented hits

Tags: regex-lookarounds

I want to write a RegEx for grep that finds source files containing a particular string, so long as it has not been commented out. That is, it should find the target string, so long as it's not preceded by the comment symbol somewhere on the same line.

I have been able to get close to the desired result using negative lookbehind, but not quite the complete solution.

The example source code is Basic, but the same puzzle would apply to other languages too.

Example statements:

```
  0010 OPEN (7)"T999"
  0020 IF A$="D" THEN OPEN (7)"T999"
```

But ignore:

```
  0030 REM OPEN (7)"T999"
  0040 REM IF A$="D" THEN OPEN (7)"T999"
```

This RegEx finds just the main string of interest.

```
  OPEN \(.+\)\"T999\"
```

This Regex

```
  (?<!REM) OPEN \(.+\)\"T999\"
```

finds lines 0010 and 0020, rejects line 0030, but includes line 0040.

That is because the lookbehind only looks at the position immediately before the main search term (minus one space).

I attempted to extend the idea like this:

```
  (?<!REM).+OPEN \(.+\)\"T999\"
```

... but that caused the lookbehind part to be ineffective, and accepted all instances of the main search, whether REM'ed or not.

So the key question appears to be how to cause the lookbehind to look a variable distance before the main search term (on the same line).

Ideas?

The grep I am using is actually FileLocator Pro, with search syntax set to Perl compatible. Purportedly following the syntax here: 
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want to find lines, not the particular text, you should start the match at the beginning of the file.

If you do want the text, use a capturing group.

Something like this:

```
(?m)^\d+\s+(?!REM).*(OPEN \(.+\)\"T999\")
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vJIrSv/1) on regex101.com.

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely a step forward in that it allows variable length content between the REM and the OPEN statement. However, it relies on finding an absence of comment marker "REM" at a specific position in the pattern, not just somewhere before the statement of interest.  So it fails to reject the following:

  `0050 A$="D" ; REM OPEN (7)"T999"`

Simple-mindedly changing the regex to: `(?m).+(?!REM).*(OPEN \(.+\)\"T999\")`
undermines the REM detection.  Any further thoughts?